# How to use previous values from Dataframe in if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame `df`

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[47,55,47,50], [33,37,30,25],[61,65,54,57],[25,26,21,22], [25,29,23,28]], columns=['open','high','low','close'])

print(df)

    open    high    low     close
0   47      55      47      50
1   33      37      30      25
2   61      65      54      57
3   25      26      21      22
4   25      29      23      20
```

I want to use previous values in if statement to compare.
Logic is as below:

```
 if (close[i-1]/close[i] > 2) and (high[i] < low[i-1]) and 
((open[i] > high[i-1]) or (open[i] <low[i-1])) :
```

I have written a code :

```
for idx,i in df.iterrows():
    if idx !=0 :
        if ((prv_close/i['close'])>2) and (i['high'] < prv_low) and ((i['open'] > prv_high) or (i['open'] < prv_low)):
            print("Successful")
        else: 
            print("Not Successful")

    prv_close = i['close']
    prv_open = i['open']
    prv_low = i['low']
    prv_high = i['high']
```

output:

```
Not Successful
Not Successful
Successful
Not Successful
```

But For millions of rows it's taking too much time. Is there any other way to implement it faster?

P.S : Action to be taken on data are different in if statement. For simplicity I'm using print statement. My columns may not have same order this is why I'm using `iterrows()` instead of `itertuples()`.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d0 = df.shift()

cond0 = (d0.close / df.close) > 2
cond1 = df.high < d0.low
cond2 = df.open > d0.high
cond3 = df.open < d0.low

mask = cond0 & cond1 & (cond2 | cond3)

mask

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work. Now I just need to get index from series **mask** for further processing.